# Operation shorturls.find() buffering timed out after 10000ms in Mongoose: How to resolve?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backend, url-shortener

I'm encountering a MongooseError when I started my server.

```
      const err = new MongooseError(message);
                  ^
```

MongooseError: Operation `shorturls.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
at Timeout. (E:\backend\url-shortener-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:198:23)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)

I was trying to run the server successfully but instead this error popped up.

Comment: This usually implies a connection issue. Can you post your code that contains your connection please?

Comment: My code is following this, its similar:
https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/url-shortener

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.